# Find all $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $X^3 + Y^3 = n$ has at least one and only finitely many rational solutions

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

I have tried some cases about this question such as $n=9$.

And I find out when $n=9$, $X^3+Y^3=9$ has infinitely many  rational solutions. This can be proved by using elliptic curves and geometric constructions. We can find tangent lines of the initial solution and then determine if this tangent line intersects  the curve or not.

But this method can only be used when you know the value of $n$ I think. I have no idea how to find out all the value of $n$ which satisfy the requirement.

Any hint or solution is appreciated. Thanks.

---

Actually there is a previous question for this question:

"Prove that the torsion points of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ are finitely many."

My solution for this question is "By the Mordell-Weil theorem, $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is a finitely generated abelian group, thus by the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, the torsion part of $E(\mathbb{Q})$  is a finite group."

Our teacher gave me this comment, "You can use the technique of the Mordell-Weil theorem to prove that rational torsion points are finite, don't apply Mordell-Weil theorem directly. Proving that torsion points are finite is far easier than the Mordell-Weil theorem." But I have no idea how to use the technique of the Mordell-Weil theorem to prove that the set of rational torsion points is finite.

Help on this question or the question about finding all $n$ is appreciated. Thanks.

---

I got a hint from my teacher but I still cannot figure it out. So I decided to post the hint here.

Hint: The general problem is this: given a rational elliptic curve of a "family", how to find all elliptic curves of this family with rank 0 and non-trivial torsion points?

Guess: there are only a limited number of good families, and there are effective algorithms.

Question: what is a good family?

Case: $Y^3+Z^3=n$

What is the method for this example?

Comment: It certainly isn't easy to understand all of the $n$ for which the curve $X^3 + Y^3 = n$ has rank zero. We expect that this to be the case for about half of the values of $n$. That said, for a given $n$ it should be straightforward to find all of the torsion points (via Nagell-Lutz for example).

Comment: $n=m^3$ has the solutions $(m,0),(0,m)$ and by fermat last theorem there are no others.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.05874.pdf for the case when $n$ is a prime number.